# inputing query with data from combobox in parentform to listbox in subform

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, subform

I have an ms-access db that has a form (FormA) with two sub forms (subFormB and subFormC). I am trying to use the value of a combobox (combo2) in FormA to get values (from a table) which will be input into subFormB and subFormC. i.e whatever values the user selects from combo2 will be used as a filter to query a table in the db and the values will be input into listboxs in either subFormB or subFormC

My code runs well with FormB but i cant seem to get it to work for FormC

The values that are displayed in combo2 depend on the  value of another combo box (combo1). 
If combo1 is "staff name" then the values in combo2 are string (names) and results are input into subFormB 
If combo1 is "project name" then the values in combo2 are numeric (numbers)and results are input into subFormC

an example of my code is below

```
Private Sub Combo2_AfterUpdate()

If Combo1 = "Staff Name" Then     
subFormB.Visible = True
ltemp = "SELECT Staff.department"
ltemp = ltemp & " FROM Staff "
ltemp = ltemp & " WHERE Staff.staff_name = '" & combo2 & "' "
Me!subFormB.Form.List3.RowSource = ltemp


If Combo1 = "Project Number" Then
subFormC.visible = True         
TID = "SELECT Contracts.TargetIssueDate"
TID = TID & " FROM Contracts "
TID = TID & " WHERE Contracts.cms = combo2 "

Me!subFormC.Form.List25.RowSource = TID
End Sub
```

In other words the first part of my code works but the second part (starting from the second if statement) doesnt. i feel it is because the value of combo2 at this instance  is numeric, and the problem is from the query but i dont know how to rewrite the query so that it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query, the *value* of `combo2` is included in the `WHERE` clause.

But the second query includes the combo's *name* instead of its value.  In other words, this is the `WHERE` clause built by the code ...

```sql
WHERE Contracts.cms = combo2
```

In that situation, I would expect Access to treat `combo2` as a parameter and ask you to supply a value for it.  But you didn't mention that, so something more may be going on.

The code includes ...

```vb
If Combo1 = "Staff Name" Then
```

... but there is no closing `End If` later.  Perhaps, you've shown us an abbreviated version of your actual code, and the actual version does include `End If`?

Rather than sorting out those details, I'll suggest a different approach.  Make a backup copy of your db file.  Use this query as the `RowSource` for `List3` on `subFormB`.

```sql
SELECT Staff.department
FROM Staff
WHERE Staff.staff_name = Forms!FormA!combo2;
```

Then, in `Combo2_AfterUpdate` of `FormA`, just `Requery` the subform's listbox, or even the entire subform, instead of altering the listbox `RowSource` ... one of these two ...

```vb
Me!subFormB!List3.Requery 
Me!subFormB.Requery
```

If that approach is satisfactory, apply the same strategy to the other subform .  And if it fails completely, revert back to your backup db.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Yes this is a very abbreviated version of the code i am working with. will try out your suggestion now